# Outline of button not fulling showing

Tags: css, wordpress, button, outline

I'm trying to give the buttons on my site the "outline" style when active, but for some reason the full outline isn't appearing. As you can see in this screenshot the top portion of the button is cut off. This didn't happen when it was just a solid button (you can see the solid buttons next to it). There isn't anything in the way to obscure the view of the outline either. Would anyone know how to correct this? Much appreciated!

[image]

```html
filter_button {
    color: #fff;
}

.vp-filter__style-default .vp-filter__item.vp-filter__item-active>* {
    background-color: #0F1B36;
    outline-style: solid;
}

.current-cat .filter_button, .filter_button:hover {
    color: #03F0F1;
}
```

Comment: Give html and css

Comment: @Marko just added the CSS to my post. The buttons are part of the Visual Portfolio plugin for WordPress, I just added a few lines of CSS to try to change to change the button style

Comment: Send me the link to the page or update the code so that output can be seen as per the image you have included.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be a margin, padding or height issue on the button as if the CSS is conflicting with another piece or element.